# determine table relationship 1 to many or 1 to 1

Tags: database-relations

I have 2 tables, and i am not sure weather it is a 1 to 1 or 1 to many relationship.

## Users table:

- UserId (PK)
- Username
- Password
- Userrole   (FK -> RoleId)

## Userroles table:

- RoleId (PK)
- UserRoleDescription
- Userrole

So in my eyes this is like this. One user can have 1 role. 1 role can have 1 user.

1 to 1 relationship.

BUUUTT.. several users can have the same role.. Im a little confused here.

Please correct me if i am wrong, i never was good determining relationships between tables.

Comment: Are you sure that an User can only have one role?. For example can a User be Administrator and Support Service?, It depends on your domain. You have to specify a little bit more if you need help with the design of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say, "several users can have the same role," you are describing a one to many relationship (one role, many users).

If it were a one to one relationship, each role would only be used once, and there would be no need to store your Roles in a separate table.

The schema you described seems appropriate.

Comment: Yea, that is one of the things i find really difficult. Maybe i have to loosen up a bit more and then i will see the golden road towards the right answer. I find your answer simple, and ofc it is a 1 to many. Thanks :)

Comment: You are on the right track with your thinking, in saying "One user can have 1 role." We can need to think about it from the role side, which would be "One role can have more than one user."